# ClassFormatError while dynamic class loading using unsafe class in java

Tags: java, mongodb

While I am running my application, that time I got `ClassFormatError` for runtime.
Like,

```
 at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:45)
       at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator+1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:381)
```

Example code:

```
    ObjectTransformer ot = null;

    try{

         JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
         if (compiler == null) {
         throw new Exception("JDK required (running inside of JRE)");
               }
            DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics =
               new  DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
           StandardJavaFileManager fm =    compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
    final JavaFileManager javaFileManager = new ForwardingJavaFileManager(fm) {
        @Override
        public JavaFileObject getJavaFileForOutput(Location location,
                                                   String className,
                                                   JavaFileObject.Kind kind,FileObject sibling) throws IOException {
            return simpleJavaFileObject;
        }
    };

    ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler().getTask(null, javaFileManager, null, null, null, singletonList(simpleJavaFileObject)).call();
    final byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();

      boolean classLoaded = true;
      Class<?> aClass = null;
      try{
        aClass = Class.forName(className);
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
        classLoaded = false;
     }
     if(!classLoaded){
        final Field f = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
         f.setAccessible(true);
         final Unsafe unsafe = (Unsafe) f.get(null);

         aClass = unsafe.defineClass(className, bytes, 0, bytes.length);
     }

     ot = (ObjectTransformer) aClass.newInstance();
     }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error  "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

How to resolve this one.. and any one knows about this, pls share knowledge to me..

Comment: I have a library to do this for you. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler work entirely in memory by default.

Comment: thnks  Peter Lawrey. but,
While am getting System Java Compiler. when i got JDK required(Instead JRE) exception..  Already i have set build path..

Comment: Yes, you need to be running in the JDK to compile code, which version of Java are you using?

Comment: java version 1.7(jdk 1.7) – Peter Lawrey

Comment: And you are definitely running from the JDK and not a JRE?

Comment: yes, am using JDK only..

Comment: Ok, when you run this program http://ideone.com/miLRmH what does it print?

Comment: java.home    /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre       because am using eclipse..

Comment: I am not sure if there is any trick to getting it working with the OpenJDK.

Comment: hai, @ Peter Lawrey.. Now i will re-opened this process. and need your help. So, check this following link. And find where am doing mistake..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41502173/how-to-created-extra-byte-at-runtime